# how to use variable values in sqlite string pattern match?

Tags: sql, sqlite, relational-database

is it possible to use variables in `LIKE` pattern matches in sqlite queries? i have the tables:

Table 1:

```
id  names  linker  
1   williams, john; jones, lisa   A1
2   jones, lisa                   A1
3   sanders, karim                A2
...
```

Table 2:

```
index  name      linker
X      williams  A1
Y      jones     A1
Z      sanders   A2
```

i want to join Table 1 to Table 2 on the `linker` column, grouped by Table2.index, but only consider entries from Table 1 where Table1.name is a substring of Table2.names, ie `Table2.names LIKE '%Table1.name%'`. in above tables `williams` entry with `id` 1 in table1 would be associated with index `X` in table2, but entry with `id` 2 of table1 would not. how can a column be used inside a pattern match? this does not work

```
select * from table1 join table2 on (table1.linker == table2.linker) where names like '%' + name + '%' group by table1.index
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL, `+` is used to add numbers. To concatenate strings, use `||`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
JOIN table2 USING (linker)
WHERE names LIKE '%' || name || '%'
GROUP BY table1.id;
```